# CSS File Refuses to Link. Instead Refers back to html

Tags: html, css, reactjs, hyperlink

Something very weird happened. I was working on a react app and all was running well until today I came back to it and my css file was not linking for some reason. The only things I did were `npm run build` and `npm run deploy`.

In my html file I have this line of code: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">`

YES my css file name is correctly spelled and YES it is in the same directory and leve as my index.html file. Still it is not being used. To test this further I put a css `<script>` into my head and it didn't work as well. Funny enough, the bootstrap that I'm using with a CDN seems to be working fine.

I put the same code in a jsfiddle and it works so it's not a problem with the code itself.

When I go to dev tools I see this:

[image]

The styles.css file is linking back to the index.html file

I have tried CTRL+SHIFT+R and clearing my chrome cache. I am very confused and would appreciate any help

EDIT: Opening the file from the path does serve the css file correctly as shown in the image below.
[image]

EDIT: It's also probably worth noting that I was messing with using `gulp` to package this project into a single html file. I followed this tutorial: https://www.labnol.org/code/bundle-react-app-single-file-200514 exactly and when it didn't work I `npm uninstall`ed all the gulp modules.

Comment: Hi Shery, indeed this is very odd. This could be some kind of caching bug, maybe try doing CTRL + SHIFT + R to force reload the document.

Comment: Hi UnReal, thanks for the suggestion, however I've tried that and it doesn't seem to work. I've also tried clearing my chrome cache.

Comment: Question: Has CSS Worked previously on this project?

Comment: Yes. In fact I have a deployed version of this project where the css is working fine.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that I tried to use gulp before to package everything into a single file. See my edit for more information.

Comment: Have you tried to link your CSS through JavaScript using `import './styles.css'` ?

Comment: I just moved my styles.css into the components directory and imported it via my App.jsx. It works now, Thank you! But there is still the question of why it was not working through the other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite clear to your issue. But since you use reactjs, you should put public url to correctly link to the file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/styles.css">
```

Note that I have not put `?v=1`. Don't do this while developing. Otherwise, you will not get updated css, you'll get cached content.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing using JS using `import './styles.css'`

> or moving the directory :)